# Can't build CertPath using CertPathBuilder

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to use Java `CertPathBuilder` to create `CertPath` from user certificate and CA certificates, but I receive

```
Exception in thread "main" sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:174)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:238)
    at CertPathBuilderTest.main(CertPathBuilderTest.java:63)
```

when I have enabled revocation checking (using `.setRevocationEnabled(true)`).
So it looks like Java is rejecting certificates or CRLs even though I can validate them using OpenSSL and gnupg without problem.

The CA structure is simplest possible: just CA signing certificates and CRLs, no intermediate CAs.

Problematic certificates: [cacerts.jks](http://lin-q.qbs.com.pl/~hka/cacerts.jks) and [private.jks](http://lin-q.qbs.com.pl/~hka/private.jks)

Example program:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CRL;
import java.security.cert.CRLException;
import java.security.cert.CertPath;
import java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder;
import java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException;
import java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderResult;
import java.security.cert.CertStore;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.CollectionCertStoreParameters;
import java.security.cert.PKIXBuilderParameters;
import java.security.cert.X509CRL;
import java.security.cert.X509CertSelector;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;

public class CertPathBuilderTest {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws CertificateException 
 * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException 
 * @throws KeyStoreException 
 * @throws CRLException 
 * @throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException 
 * @throws UnexpectedJCAException 
 * @throws SigningCertChainException 
 * @throws CertPathBuilderException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException, CRLException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, CertPathBuilderException
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // keytool -importcert -file CA.pem -keystore cacerts.jks -storepass changeit
    KeyStore trustAnchors = loadJKSKeyStore("cacerts.jks", "changeit");
    KeyStore myKeyStore = loadJKSKeyStore("private.jks", "changeit");

    String crlLocation = "http://crl.qbs.com.pl/QBSJanKuban.crl";
    X509CRL crl = downloadCRL(crlLocation);

    CertStore cs = otherCertificatesCertStore(trustAnchors, myKeyStore, crl);
    ///*
    CertPathBuilder cpb = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX");
    X509CertSelector certSelector = new X509CertSelector();
    certSelector.setCertificate((X509Certificate) myKeyStore.getCertificate("mykey"));
    PKIXBuilderParameters cpp = new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustAnchors, certSelector);
    cpp.addCertStore(cs);
    cpp.setRevocationEnabled(true);
    cpp.setMaxPathLength(6);
    cpp.setDate(new Date());

    CertPathBuilderResult a = cpb.build(cpp);
    CertPath certPath = a.getCertPath();
}

private static KeyStore loadJKSKeyStore(String path, String password)
    throws KeyStoreException,
    NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");
    ks.load(fis, password.toCharArray());
    fis.close();
    return ks;
}

private static X509CRL downloadCRL(String crlLocation)
        throws IOException, CertificateException, CRLException
{
    URL crlURL = new URL(crlLocation);
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(crlURL.openStream());

    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    CRL crl = cf.generateCRL(in);

    return (X509CRL) crl;
}

private static CertStore otherCertificatesCertStore(KeyStore trustAnchors,
        KeyStore myCerts, X509CRL... crl)
        throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException
{

    CertStore cs;

    Collection<Object> contentList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    contentList.add(trustAnchors.getCertificate("qbsca"));
    contentList.add(myCerts.getCertificate("mykey"));
    for (int i=0; i < crl.length; i++) {
        contentList.add(crl[i]);
    }
    cs = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(contentList));

    return cs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was caused by a bug(?) in SUN and BC cryptographic providers.

When the user certificate has specified not only `CRL Distribution Point` in form of URI, but also `CRL Issuer` then CertPathBuilder isn't able to verify the validity of CRL and whole process fails.

The workaround is to create certificates lacking this extension.

Comment: @owlstead: no problem. I try to post solutions to questions if I find them, I know damn well how frustrating it is to find just "I figured it out" or no answer what so ever...